# Setting up Konica7020 on a Network

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, drivers, printer

This printer has been the bane of my existence for the past two days.

I am supposed to get the Konica7020 setup so that it will work with Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 and I can send print jobs to it and it prints but it doesn't print the document I sent, instead it prints out information sent to the Konica.

I strongly believe all the issues stem from the drivers, the latest drivers for the Konica 7020 that I've found are dated to Windows XP and it just doesn't seem to work.

I've tried to search online for printer/postscript drivers but finding an official one might be impossible, at least for me. d point me towards a trustworthy driver site that could contain it.

UPDATE:

I'm curious if anyone else has attempted a similar setup or coul
So I've gotten further along with finding the error, still haven't solved the issue.

Reading through the documentation it does print, I've noticed that VM error has popped up a few times in the Pscript_WinNT_ErrorHandler 5.0.0 file. Also in the same file I see the lines

```
{(ERROR: )prnt errorname prnt nl (OFFENDING COMMAND: )prnt/command load prnt repeat}
```

Later on under Pscript_FatalError 5.0.0

```
/Encoding{ISOLatin1Encoding}stopped{StandardEncoding}if def currentdict end /ErrFont-Latin1 exch definefont}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with old equipment and old drivers. The XP drivers are not likely to work with Windows 7 or 8. Hence, you are having problems printing.

It is a long shot, but you can try Konica's [Universal Driver](http://www.biz.konicaminolta.com/technologies/upd/spec.html). If not, you may be out of options using old equipment with Windows 7 & 8.